# Listview performance issue in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin.Android and I made a very simple app and I compared it to the same app developed in Java and got results that I can't believe in.

Everything that this app is doing is populating ListView with 10000 items on a button click.

C# code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var list = new List<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        list.Add(i.ToString());

    var adapter = 
     new ArrayAdapter<String(this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, list);
    listView.Adapter = adapter;
}
```

Java code:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
                list.add(Integer.toString(i));

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
```

I measured the performance and these are the results:
Xamarin.Android: approx. 950 ms 
Java: less than 1 ms

How and why? What am I doing wrong?

I think that in Java not all items are populated at the same time but in Xamarin.Android are, if that is the case how can I avoid it and make populating ListView a lot faster?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance/

Comment: Can you provide Android code?

Comment: Java code is equivalent to C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Xamarin.Android: approx. 950 ms Java: less than 1 ms.

When you use `new ArrayAdapter(..)` method to populate `ListView`, if you just populate a small amount of data(less then about 100), it has little difference between `Xamarin.Android` and `Java`. With the increase of the data, the performance has little change in `Java`, but in `Xamarin.Android`, the time spend to loaded time is proportional to the amount of data.

In my M6 with Android 7.0, when I populate `ListView` with 100,000 data, `Xamarin.Android` : approx. 4200 ms, `Java` : approx. 42 ms.

> If that is the case how can I avoid it and make populating ListView a lot faster?

For a better performance you can create a [custom Adapter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview's_appearance/#Referencing_a_Custom_Row_View) to populating `ListView`. If you want to populating mass of data, it is suggested to use [RecyclerView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/#Putting_it_All_Together). I use it in my device to populate 100,000 data, both of them has a good performance in `Xamarin.Android` : approx. 200 ms.

Comment: @RooT, can this help you ?

Comment: Yes it helps but 200ms compared to 42ms is still a bit slow. How does it scale with complex data, did you do benchmark?

Comment: would like to know that to :)